# How to recognize which browser window corresponds to an ID in system monitor

Tags: browser, memory-usage, cpu-load

Given multiple open browser windows, I would like to recognize which one corresponds to a specific ID given in the system monitor.

Is there any way to find the window given its ID?

Answer (score 0):

Install [`wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html) if necessary, then list your windows with `wmctrl -l` to find out their IDs. For example,

```
$ wmctrl -l
0x02a00002  0 fractina XdndCollectionWindowImp
0x02a00005  0 fractina unity-launcher
0x02a00008  0 fractina unity-panel
0x02a0000b  0 fractina unity-dash
0x02a0000c  0 fractina Hud
0x02c0000a  0 fractina Desktop
0x03600010  0 fractina memory usage - How to recognize which browser window corresponds to an ID in system monitor - Ask Ubuntu - Mozilla Firefox
0x03e0000a  0 fractina alexp@fractina: ~
```

It may be the case that you want process IDs and not window IDs; you can use `wmctrl -lp` to show the process IDs for the processes running in each window.